# Is it possible to trigger multiple journeys in MC at the same time (not scheduling method)

Tags: marketing-cloud

My client has their own contact policy process built in MC, the concept is everyday all campaigns need to pass its eligible records to this contact policy process, when the contact policy process is completed. Each campaign's automation will pick its records and put in their journey entry source.

Normally this contact policy process start at noon and finish around 1.30 PM.
After that each campaign's automation will start extract the data from contact policy output DE at 2.30 PM.

The problem is if some problem occurred then contact policy cannot finish on time, but it completes after 2.30 pm then all campaigns has no entry sources for that day.

How can we handle this situation?
Does SFMC has concept global trigger/event to just start multiple automations/journeys?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no built-in global trigger or event in SFMC that can directly initiate multiple automation or journeys based on the completion of a process. You might have to design a workaround monitoring the contact policy process and having a backup solution in case the policy process cannot finish in time.
Automation Studio, Custom Scripts and other tools can come to the rescue.

Comment: Thanks @VijayaKapadam